# Why does Win10 not auomaticly grow the page file

Tags: windows-10, virtual-memory

The page file size on my Windows 10 64bit with 16GB phyiscal RAM is managed by Windows automaticly. The system tells me that the size is currently 2,38 GB. So the virtual RAM is 18,1 GB.

When I "do data science" (e.g. Python3 pandas) a lot of RAM is used. From time to time I got memory exceptions because there is not enouhg RAM anymore.

I would assume that Windows would grow the page file if a process need more RAM. Why not?

Comment: How much space is left on the pagefile's volume?

Comment: Does this behavior change if you manually increase the pagefile? Be aware that not every block in RAM can be paged-out into the page file (non-pageable pool).